# angular2 routing : Cannot read property 'toUrlPath' of null

Tags: angular

I am using beta-0, and hashlocationstrategy, but when I enter this url localhost/#/searchh which is not registered in my config, 
and the error show

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUrlPath' of null
```

routeconfig:

```
@RouteConfig([
{path: '/'   ,   name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
{path: '/search', name: 'Search', component: SearchComponent },
{ path: '/project/:id', name: 'Project', component: ProjectComponent },
])
```

even I am using redirectTo in my '/' path, it stills show the message, what's wrong?

and more problem is enter to /#/project/1232132 which is more than I have, it seems show the template, but empty details because I just have 3 projects, it should be worked /#/project/3, how can I fix this? create error page in ng2?
the error message is

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in [{{project.title}} in ProjectComponent@0:52]
```

Comment: this is because angular is enable to find `path` you specify and angular is enable to bind the routing to that `URL`. and second error as clarify from the name `titile` is undefined , try using `elvis operator` i.e `?` like this `{{project?.title}}`

Answer (score 1):

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in [{{project.title}} in ProjectComponent@0:52]

I solved it with ngIf:

```
<h2 *ngIf="project">{{project.title}}</h2>
```

EDIT: 
or as Günter and Pardeep suggest, you can do that with the elvis operator:

```
<h2>{{project?.title}}</h2>
```

Comment: I guess there should be a `?` before `.title` => `{{project?.title}}`

Comment: yes exactly `elvis operator` for the object which may have some values